# Embedded error: When analyzing c# projects

Tags: sonarqube

I got an Embedded error when analyzing a c sharp projects. 
 Please help me to solve this issue.

here is my log file data.

```
 [INFO] [10:34:52.875] Inside Core CppPlugin.getExtension()
 [INFO] [10:34:53.140] Selected quality profile : [name=Sonar C# Way,language=cs]

 [INFO] [10:34:53.203] Configure maven plugins...
 [INFO] [10:34:53.250] Compare to previous analysis
 [INFO] [10:34:53.296] Compare over 5 days (2012-12-09)
 [INFO] [10:34:53.296] Compare over 30 days (2012-11-14)
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [ERROR] BUILD ERROR
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] Can not execute Sonar

 Embedded error: org.sonar.plugin.dotnet.coverity.CoveritySensor has unsatisfied
 dependency 'class org.sonar.plugins.csharp.api.MicrosoftWindowsEnvironment' for
 constructor 'public org.sonar.plugin.dotnet.coverity.CoveritySensor(org.sonar.ap
 i.resources.ProjectFileSystem,org.sonar.api.profiles.RulesProfile,org.sonar.plug
 in.dotnet.coverity.CoverityProfileExporter,org.sonar.plugin.dotnet.coverity.Cove
 rityResultParser,org.sonar.plugins.csharp.api.CSharpConfiguration,org.sonar.plug
 ins.csharp.api.MicrosoftWindowsEnvironment)' from org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoC
 ontainer@1f541ef:178<[Immutable]:org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer@b38dba:2
 42<[Immutable]:org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer@2a7640:47<|
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] Total time: 36 seconds
 [INFO] Finished at: Fri Dec 14 10:34:53 IST 2012
 [INFO] Final Memory: 19M/38M
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you got this "Sonar Coverity" plugin (it is not part of the Sonar Plugins Forge), but it looks like you're trying to use this plugin while you haven't installed the .NET & C# plugins yet...

Comment: yes. i removed the Coverity plugin. Now its working perfectly. Thanks Fabrice